# Could photons orbit a black hole if fired at the correct angle?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, black-hole, light

My experience with Kerbal Space Program gives me the impression that it's impossible to transfer from a stable orbit of one body to the stable orbit of another without deceleration. But is this true for a photon? Could light enter a stable orbit of a black hole if fired at the correct angle from a distance?

Comment: I was wondering if starlight could build up near the orbital altitude of a black hole, creating a brief flash of light for any matter falling below that altitude.

Comment: @StarMan I know about that, but my question had more to do with the entry of photons from outside of the photon sphere into it, and more broadly the orbital mechanics of photons.

Comment: @WesleyAdams Well then how did light enter the photon sphere in the first place? The photons had to be fired into the sphere. Thus answering your question (mostly)

Comment: @WesleyAdams in the mean time, you may enjoy reading answers to [Could a trajectory around a large mass ever deflect by more than 180 degrees due to general relativistic effects?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/467144/83380) from what I see there unbound orbits stay unbound and bound orbits stay bound, but those are ballistic trajectories, and you've asked about *photons.*

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [this](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/29620/can-a-photon-have-a-stable-orbit-around-a-black-hole).  The answer is no because there are no stable photon orbits (there are however *unstable* photon orbits) (I dont have enough reputation to recommend this be closed as a duplicate I think).

Comment: @uhoh This information was the basis for my question. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can light be trapped in orbit?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/25552/can-light-be-trapped-in-orbit)

Answer (score 6):

There are no **stable** photon orbits around black holes ([see this answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/29777/7982)).

Black holes do have an *unstable* photon orbit though. "Unstable" here means that any tiny deviation from this orbit, will case the photon to be either scattered to infinity or sent into the black hole. It should be emphasized that there such orbits are always circular an can exist at only one radius (1.5 times the Schwarzschild radius for a Schwarzschild black hole). There are no elliptic photon orbits. This orbit is often called the "light ring" (or sometimes "photonsphere")

As long as we treat the photon as a perfect massless point (test) particle, we can find a highly fine-tuned trajectory that will asymptote to the light-ring. Of course, in reality, a photon always needs to be a wave packet with a finite size, making this fine tuning impossible in practice.

Comment: Can a photon emitted from a distant location be captured into an orbit if not emitted from a point that intersects with that orbit?

Comment: You don’t have stable photon orbits, so a photon cannot be captured in one.

Comment: But as I said for any unstable orbit you can find a trajectory that approaches it asymptotically.

Comment: Do the photons on such orbits move in the same direction as black hole's spin?

Comment: If a photon shifts inward from such orbit, how many revolution it still can do before being swallowed by the event horizon?

Comment: @Anixx Feel free to ask those questions as separate questions.